# Why is Mr. Keefe blaming Bruce?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* Wallace Keefe (employee of Wayne) -  Was the person who lost his both legs while Superman fought with [General Zod](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000225/?ref_=tt_cl_t3).

Bruce Wayne's company had been paying into a victims' fund for him (Keefe) every month and he returns them writing below lines on cheques.

1. BRUCE WAYNE OPEN YOUR EYES
2. B. WAYNE I AM YOUR GHOST
3. BRUCE NO TRUCE
4. B. WAYNE I HAUNT YOU
5. BRUCE WAYNE = BLIND
6. YOU LET Your FAMILY DIE

Now the question is, why he is he blaming Bruce? For what reason? Did he know that Bruce is Batman and he never tried to stop Superman? And Above this all, Bruce is the person who saved his life from that accident?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keefe doesn't send those cheques, Lex does.

When Superman confronts Lex Luthor on the roof of LexCorp, Lex says something along the lines of that it only took "a few well placed letters" to convince Bruce to fight Superman.

We can infer that Lex had been intercepting the cheques to Keefe, and sending them back to Bruce in order to get him to further blame Superman for Keefe's injuries, and subsequent death, and thus convince him to attempt to kill Superman (as Lex knows that Bruce Wayne is Batman).

It would also drive Keefe to further desperation if he has not been receiving the money from Bruce Wayne, allowing him to be more easily manipulated into committing suicide and destroying the Capitol building when Superman arrives for the hearing.

Comment: Yes. On the roof Lex said to Superman **"Little red notes, big bang. You let your family die"**